# does the Zw at the beginning of some of the win functions actually stand for anything

Tags: windows, visual-c++, driver

Curious to know if the `Zw` I see on some windows functions (usually driver functions) actually stands for something, example: `ZwQueryInformationProcess`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/what-does-the-zw-prefix-mean-

Comment: https://community.osr.com/discussion/198193/win32k-internals